# SQL Query Issue to get last 12 Months data from a DE in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, sfmc-business-unit, sqlserver, sql-studio

I am trying to get the data from a DE for last 12 months but when I am running my Query, I am only getting data November 2022 but I want to have data from each month after from November 2022 till now to get the data of last 12 months.

below is my query

```
Select P.AB__c,
       P.GB__c,
       P.Period__c,
       P.Account__c,
       B.Pd,
       B.bt
FROM ProdData P
    INNER JOIN send_general B
        ON P.Account__c = B.AccountId
Where DATEPART(M, P.Period__c) = DATEPART(M, DATEADD(M, -12, GETDATE()))
      AND DATEPART(yyyy, P.Period__c) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(M, -12, getdate()))
```

Please help me with this query to get the data from last 12 months.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample data -- of the related tables and the desired output.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs , it worked for me. Thank you for your response! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is only getting the data for **November 2022** because you are using the `=` operator to compare the **month** and **year** parts of the date. This means that you are only selecting the records that match exactly the same month and year as 12 months ago from the current date.

[To get the data for the last 12 months](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-date-functions/), you need to use the `>=` operator instead, which will select the records that are greater than or equal to the date 12 months ago from the current date.

For example, your query should look something like this:

```sql
Select 
  P.AB__c
, P.GB__c
, P.Period__c
, P.Account__c
, B.Pd
, B.bt 
FROM ProdData P 
INNER JOIN send_general B ON P.Account__c = B.AccountId 
Where 
P.Period__c >= DATEADD(M, -12, GETDATE())
```

Also, [you can use the **DATEDIFF** function to compare the difference between two dates in terms of months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049478/how-can-i-get-the-last-12-months-from-the-current-date-plus-extra-days-till-1st). This will return the number of months between the two dates, and you can use the `<=` operator to select the records that are within the **last 12 months** from the current date.

For example, your query should look something like this:

```sql
Select 
  P.AB__c
, P.GB__c
, P.Period__c
, P.Account__c
, B.Pd
, B.bt 
FROM ProdData P 
INNER JOIN send_general B ON P.Account__c = B.AccountId 
Where 
DATEDIFF(M, P.Period__c, GETDATE()) <= 12
```

I hope one of these solutions works for you.